# How to fix pacman error about /etc being to full?

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I am trying to install redis with pacman in steam deck desktop mode and I get the following
error: Partition /etc too full: 11891 blocks needed, 750 blocks free

Here is the ouput of df -h
[image: df -h]

Comment: please never post screenshots of text. it's really easy to just copy the text and paste it verbatim to your question, which makes it searchable and copyable and whatnot)

Answer (score 0):

`pacman` installs packages.
The files typically go into `/usr`, but configuration files will be installed into `/etc`.

In order for this to work, it needs to be able to store stuff in these directories, which means that they must not be (too) *full* before starting.

So if `pacman` complains that your `Partition [is] /etc too full`, than it probably is just right about this, and you should be grateful that it refuses to risk corrupt data.

The solution is obviously to resize the partition you are trying to write to.